# Optimize code in JavaScript (Currently using too many for loops)

Tags: javascript, for-loop, data-structures

I have been working on a data formating question, and finally got the answer.

However, my answer has too many loops, and it will slow down time complexity when implementing.

Below is my code:

```js
const userInfo = [];

for (let i = 0; i < projects.length; i++) {
  const userProject = projects[i].userProjects;

  for (let j = 0; j < userProject.length; j++) {
    const userExist = userInfo.some((item) =>
      item.userId.includes(userProject[j].user.userId)
    );
    if (!userExist) userInfo.push(userProject[j].user);
  }
}

userInfo.forEach((user) => {
  let tempArr = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < projects.length; i++) {
    const userProject = projects[i].userProjects;
    for (let j = 0; j < userProject.length; j++) {
      if (user.userId === userProject[j].userId)
        tempArr.push({
          projectId: projects[i].projectId,
          name: projects[i].name,
        });
    }
  }
  user.project = tempArr;
});

console.log(userInfo);
```

Is there a way I can optimize my code? I tried to combine the nested for loops together but not working...

Please help. Thank you so much!!!

Comment: What you need is a better data structure that is organized according to what your application needs to do.

Comment: Share your data & please tell what is the expected output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the top part, the outer two loops look necessary (since you have N projects * M userProjects), but the third `.some` isn't - change the `userInfo` from an array to a mapping of userIds to their users, so inside the second loop, you only have to look up to see if the userId already exists (`O(1)`), and assign if it doesn't.

Instead of assigning the user, assign an object of the shape you need at the end - a `[{ projectId, name }]`. This'll save you from having to go through the whole array again - once you've checked to see if you need to create the surrounding array for the `userId`, you can push the object to the array whether or not you had to create the array on that iteration or not.

```
const userProjectsByUserId = new Map();
for (const { userProjects, projectId, name } of projects) {
    for (const { user } of projects) {
        if (!userProjectsByUserId.has(user.userId)) {
            userProjectsByUserId.set(user.userId, { user, projects: [] }]);
        }
        userProjectsByUserId.get(user.userId).projects.push({ projectId, name });
    }
}
```

This'll give you a Map of the shape

```
userId => {
  user,
  projects: [
    { projectId, name },
    ...
```

If you need exact data structure your current code is giving you, then afterwards, do:

```
const output = [...userProjectsByUserId.values()]
  .map(({ user, projects }) => ({ ...user, project: projects }));
```

(though you might consider using `projects` instead of `project`, since it's a collection of projects, not a single project)

Comment: Thank you so much. What if not using the data structure new Map(), instead, using Array?

Comment: If you use an array, you won't be able to immediately look up the userId in it - instead, you'll have to search through the array for a match (`O(n)`) instead of just looking it up as a property of the Map or object (`O(1)`). So, don't use an array when grouping; it'll make things too inefficient.

Comment: Got it, thank you so much for your help!!